# Is there a Data.Binary instance for Data.Time.Calendar.Day?

Tags: haskell

Is there a `Data.Binary` instance for `Data.Time.Calendar.Day`?

More generally, what is one supposed to do if `Data.Binary` have not been provided for a particular datatype in a widely used library?

Answer (score 1):

If you just create a `Binary` instance and place it in your module then you'll be creating an orphan instance which can cause a lot of confusion later when someone imports your module---it'll drag along that orphan instance and possibly conflict with their understanding of how dates should be made `Binary`.

If you have a very canonical instance, try pushing it to the library author. It's easy to add the instance if it's a good idea and it can benefit anyone who uses that library.

If that isn't an option (or if you have a non-canonical instance) then you probably want to create a `newtype` wrapper. They're "free" in that the compiler deletes them automatically, but they allow a type to take on an entirely new identity with new typeclass instances.

I've done this before to handle particular parses of, for instance, "dates in *this* format" compared to `Date` broadly.

Comment: One might add that orphan instances are not so bad in application code (in contrast to libraries which are meant to be used by others).

Comment: Absolutely: the problem arises when your library provides instances unexpectedly.